# BASH Shellscript get username from folder path

Tags: linux, bash, shell, debian

Given a folder path that has `/home`, I would like to scrape the username from the folder path. (A little home work, trying to compare folder username to actual owner of the folder, which can be determined with a quick `stat -c '%U' path`

```
Input1: /home/user1/Music
Output1: user1

Input2: /home/user2
Output2: user2

Input3: /home
Output3: root
```

I have managed to come up with something that is able to cater to Input1, but I am unable to come up with something to cater to the other two inputs.

`owner=$(path | grep -oP '(?<=home/).*(?=/)')`
This will scrape anything that is between `home/` and the next `/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of a hack

```
owner=$(cut -d/ -f3 <<< "$path/root")
```

A more complete answer to deal with input 3 in the form `Input3: /home/` or paths like `/home//user3`

```
owner=$(tr -s '/' <<< "$path/root" | cut -d/ -f3)
```

Comment: Very nice! However, is there no other way to ensure that if the input is like `/home` or `/Anotherfolder` without a user name defined, it will default to `root`? (input 3) I can just let the user know to end the string with '/' if that's all I can do

EDIT: silly me, you just force a /root behind to simulate a root path. Wonderful!

Answer (score 1):

You can trry this:

```
owner=$(echo $path | tr '/' ' ' | awk '{print $2}')
if [ "$owner" == "" ]
    then echo root
else
    echo $owner
fi
```

Hope this helps. But I would recommend to use `ls -l` command and extract owner from there.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use `ls` command to get path either owner, then parse it by `awk`.

`ls -lp /home | grep "/$" | tr -d '/' | awk '{print "Input:", $9, "\nOwner:", $3, "\n"}'`